# Make X509Certificate2 accessible after validation via ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

I am using a `HttpClientHandler` with a custom `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback`.

I need, or at least would like to have, access to the certificate chain and the server certificate after the request is done.
At the moment I just put both of them in class variables for access later.

Is this possible?

The behavior I'm seeing now is such that both objects cant be accessed after the validation.
I currently get a `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException` when I try to inspect the server certificate in my debugger. The chain appears to be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you face is caused because objects are disposed after leaving callback. You can copy certificate to local variable as follows:

```
class MyClass {
    static X509Certificate2 localCert; // must be static
    void MyMethod() {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, error) =>
        {
            localCert = new X509Certificate2(cert.RawData);
            // continue validation and return value
           ...
        };
        // do TLS connection
        ...
    }
}
```

chain copy is a bit more complex, because you cannot serialize it. However, you can try to use p/invoke and duplicate chain handle by calling [CertDuplicateCertificateChain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certduplicatecertificatechain) function and passing existing chain handle as a parameter. That is, create another static field of type of `X509Chain` and assign it this way inside callback function:

```
localChain = new X509Chain(Win32.CertDuplicateCertificateChain(chain.ChainContext));
```

function definition may be like this:

```
static class Win32 {
    [DllImport("crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CertDuplicateCertificateChain(IntPtr pChainContext);
    [DllImport("crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern void CertFreeCertificateChain(IntPtr pChainContext);
}
```

do not forget to manually dispose your local chain instance to avoid memory leak. I haven't tested this approach to copy chain, but this is what I would try first.

Comment: I managed to copy the server certificate with the `Export():byte[]` and `Import(byte[]):void` methods. 
Your method for the Chain does work. I assume I just pass the ChainContext into `CertFreeCertificateChain()` or is a `.Dispose()` enough?

Comment: `Dispose` is enough. In previous .NET versions, `X509Chain` doesn't implement `IDisposable`, in these cases you have to call unmanaged function. And you don't need to export/import certificate, just construct local field from `X509Certificate2.RawData`, which is simpler and faster.